# Is "You smell like sweat." the idiomatic way of saying it?

Tags: idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

If you want to say to a close friend, who has sweated too much and is stinking because of that, which do you use?

1. **You smell like sweat.**
2. **You smell of sweat.**
3. **You smell sweat.**
4. **You smell sweaty.**

I checked Ngram but **"You smell like sweat"** is shown highest.
[image: sweat]

I can't be sure if **"You smell like sweat"** is correct. This sentence sounds like the person is not sure about the kind of the smell, because of the word "like". This means the odor resembles sweat or reminds them of sweat whereas it is actually sweat itself.

Is this really how native speakers of English say it?

Comment: #4 is idiomatic, not so much the others. Note that since *fresh* sweat has little or no odour, anyone saying this would almost certainly mean *You smell like **stale** sweat* - which is far more strongly implied by #4 than by #1 or #2. Also note that #3 is simply "invalid" unless you're pointing out that the other person can smell (detect by nose) the odour of sweat (from an unspecified source).

Comment: ***Also*** note that your chart makes useless comparisons. NGrams are case-sensitive, but your search strings are a random mix of capitalisations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks. I did not know it was case sensitive. So, I checked it -correctly- once again and "You smell like sweat" -number 1- is shown the highest, but as far as I understand you comment, you say number 4 is idiomatic, but ngram yielded number 1 as the highest. Did I miss something?

Comment: Tempted to downvote because of the smell.

Comment: "You smell like sweat" has **no hint of** "kind of similar to a bad smell" at all. It means your smell is very close to the smell of sweat, a bad smell.

Comment: Be aware that good English or not, all your choices are insulting to anyone who's not your own sibling. Not similar to an insult, exactly like an insult. Maybe try "Did you get a shower after your workout?" "You might be a tad ripe."

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would simply say **you stink**.

Comment: Or, perhaps more politely, **you smell bad**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I disagree. Personally I would be more annoyed by a passive agressive "did you get a shower after your workout?" than by a frank and honest "you smell sweaty". Of course it depends on the tone and context.

Comment: Avoid searching phrases on ngram from 1800, instead begin with 1900 and onwards for more up-to-date results.  You were right, N.1  appears to be the most popular phrase: [**you smell like sweat**,you smell of sweat,you smell sweaty](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+smell+like+sweat%2Cyou+smell+of+sweat%2Cyou+smell+sweaty&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for 3 (which  is the transitive verb "smell" and means "detect an odour", instead of "give off an odour") these are all possible.

"You smell like sweat" is fine.  The most common reason for a person to smell like sweat is that they are covered in sweat.  You can say "like" sweat, since you don't imply that the person is made of sweat.

But the others are also good ways to express the same general idea.  I don't see much difference between them.  [My ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smells+like+sweat%2Csmells+of+sweat%2Csmells+sweaty&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests "smell of sweat" is the most common.  Possibly "smell sweaty" would be more common in spoken English.

Comment: The Ngram chart has the 3rd person singular "smells" which could refer to a person, thing or animal. E.g *it smells sweaty here*.

Comment: I find 'You smell like sweat" unidiomatic. The speaker knows what it is that the person smells of, they are not saying "You have a smell (that I can't identify) resembling that of sweat."

Comment: Yes, I chose the 3rd person to avoid getting hits for "the smell of sweat" that would skew the results.  I have no problem at all with smells like sweat, when the smell really is from sweat.  Google books finds "He smells like sweat and motor oil...", "my mattress smells like sweat; from all those days and nights" "She smells like sweat and cigarettes. It reminds me of home." and so on.

Comment: In AmE, "smell of sweat" is a tad formal  whereas "smell sweaty" and "smell like sweat" are colloquial.  Someone who hasn't gone beyond secondary school isn't likely to say "smell of sweat".

Comment: @KateBunting: It sounds to me like you're disagreeing with this answer then. Which is weird, because you did not produce any sound that I observed in order to understand that you didn't quite agree. Huh. I guess language is able to convey its intended meaning without necessarily needing to be pedantically correct. Additionally, it would still be polite to not outright state that it is indeed sweat, given that there may be other things that smell similarly and you don't want to be making unconfirmed accusations.

Comment: @Flater - 'Produce any sound'? Do you mean that I didn't say that I disagreed? I said that I, personally, didn't find that version natural. If I walked into a newly-decorated room I would say "It still smells of paint in here", not "It smells _like_ paint", because it would be obvious what the source of the smell was. Apparently American usage may be different.

Comment: I agree that "smell like sweat" is not natural. It is grammatically correct but, for me, its use would indicate a non-native speaker. Is this possibly an American / British difference? "smell of sweat" is definitely more idiomatic than "like".

Comment: Your ngram search has examples with **smells**, so "smells of sweat" may be the  most common. But as I mentioned earlier, it could refer to a third party, an animal or a thing.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22smells%20like%20sweat%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:2016&lr=lang_en Please look at the examples cited by Google Books.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+smell+like+sweat%2Cyou+smell+of+sweat%2Cyou+smell+sweaty&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 Interesting results. Until 2000 it appears "you smell of sweat" was most commonly used when it was sharply overtaken by "**you smell like sweat**"

Comment: @KateBunting: Your paint example implies that you were already previously aware of the smell in the room coming from the paint. The point of using "like" is to _not outright assert knowledge_. Reasons for doing so include genuinely not knowing for sure, or if being assertive about it would be considered rude or impolite. I think we already agree on the former case; but I'm bringing this up specifically because of the latter case.

Comment: @KateBunting - there is a famous 1990s American rock music album called 'Smells like Teen Spirit' whose title is immediately understandable to anyone who has worked with adolescents. Kind of goaty, and I think the apocrine glands are involved.